# Change the variable with multiple colors - scss

Tags: css, sass

Hello i want to change the background of a page while dark mode.

this is the regular background

```
$orangeLight:#FFA500!default;
$redLight:#FA8072!default;
$blueLight:#B0C4DE!default;
$greenLight:#90EE90!default;

$list2: $blueLight 0%,$blueLight 25%,$greenLight 25%,$greenLight 50%, $orangeLight 50%, $orangeLight 75%, $redLight 75%, $redLight 100%!default;

 .three {
    @include gradient(to top, $list2);
 }

 <ion-content [class.dark-theme]="dark" class="three">
   some content
 </ion-content>
```

and i want to implement class three on dark mode. I thought about redefining the $list2 variable

```
.dark-theme{
 $orangeLight:#FF8C00;
 $redLight:#8B0000;
 $blueLight:#00008B;
 $greenLight:#006400;

 $list2: $blueLight 0%,$blueLight 25%,$greenLight 25%,$greenLight 50%, $orangeLight 50%,      $orangeLight 75%, $redLight 75%, $redLight 100%;

ion.content{
 background-image: $list2;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

sass variables are not persisted after compiled, meanwhile css variables you can access and manipulate at javscript level. For theming I would go with css variables (its declaration is not really pretty but that's ok). With css variables you can handle it with vanilla javascript directly. if you are using a SPA of sorts, you could store themes as some state control, and also handle it properly:

```js
const themes = {
 defaultTheme: [
 ['--orangeLight', '#FFA500'],
 ['--redLight', '#FA8072'],
 ['--blueLight', '#B0C4DE'],
 ['--greenLight', '#90EE90'],
 ],
 darkTheme: [
  ['--orangeLight', '#FF8C00'],
  ['--redLight', '#8B0000'],
  ['--blueLight', '#00008B'],
  ['--greenLight', '#006400'],
  ]
}

let theme = 'defaultTheme'

const button = document.querySelector('#color-changer')

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
 theme = theme === 'defaultTheme' ? 'darkTheme' : 'defaultTheme'
 console.log(theme)
 updateTheme(theme)
})

function updateTheme(theme) {
 themes[theme].forEach(setCssVariable)
}

function setCssVariable ([variable, value]) { document.body.style.setProperty(variable, value) }
```

```css
html { 
 font-size:62.5%;
 --orangeLight: #FFA500;
 --redLight: #FA8072;
 --blueLight: #B0C4DE;
 --greenLight: #90EE90;
}

button {
 margin: 4px;
 padding: 4px;
 background: yellowgreen;
}

.container {
 width: 300px;
  padding: 12px;
  background: var(--greenLight);
}

.header {
 padding: 8px;
 background: var(--orangeLight);
}

.content {
 padding: 8px;
 margin: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
 background: var(--blueLight);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
  <div class="content">1</div>
  <div class="content">2</div>
  <div class="content">3</div>
 </div>
</div>

<button id="color-changer">Change Theme</button>
```

Comment: Thanks buzatto but i am using Ionic 3

Comment: At docs they provide approaches using css variables as well. https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/themes. I hope it clarifies for you some possibilities.